# Troubles with case of files extensions on Windows

Tags: linux, cmd, makefile

I have a makefile I use under both Linux and windows using arm-none-eabi tool chain. The project contains assembler files with either .s or .S extension depending on the need of the preprocessor.

Under Linux, the makefile rules can easily distinguish those target files and separate rules are use for each of them. No problem in this world.
Under Windows, the rules I defined to treat the .S files fails to handle these files. On the other hand, my rule for .s files works well.

Error returned is :

```
make: Pas de règle pour fabriquer la cible « obj/secmodes.S », nécessaire pour « imgm_essProcMode.elf ». Arrêt.

No rule to build the target obj/secmode.S, required for imgm_essProcMode.elf. Stop
```

I don't understand why the path of the source is incorrect : all .s, .S, .c are in "src" folder ; "obj" folder is used for generated objects...
I realized windows does not care of the extension case ! This seems to confuse (gnu) make.

So my question is, can we manage .s and .S differently in a makefile executed in Windows environment ? If so, how my rules shall be modified for that ?

Here some snaps of my makefile:

```
AOBJ_FILES := $(addprefix obj/,$(notdir $(ASM_FILES:.s=.o)))
ASOBJ_FILES := $(addprefix obj/,$(notdir $(ASMS_FILES:.S=.o)))
ALL_OBJ_FILES := $(COBJ_FILES) $(AOBJ_FILES) $(ASOBJ_FILES) 
.../...
image : $(BINEXECUTABLE)

all : $(EXECUTABLE)

obj/%.o: src/%.S
    $(TCPREFIX)-gcc $(AOPTgcc) -Xassembler -acdghln=$(basename $@).lst -o $@ $<

obj/%.o: src/%.s
    $(TCPREFIX)-as $(AOPT) $< -o $@ -acdghln=$(basename $@).lst

obj/%.o: src/%.c
    $(TCPREFIX)-gcc $(COPT) -Wa,-acdghln=$(basename $@).lst $(DEFINES) -o $@ $<

$(EXECUTABLE): $(ALL_OBJ_FILES)
    $(TCPREFIX)-gcc $(LOPTgcc) $^ -o $@
```

Thank you for any hint !

Comment: Put them in different folders if possible

Comment: How is this related to [tag:cmd], the Windows command prompt?

Comment: aschipfl : this is cmd.exe that executes make and does not distinguish cases. If this is not cmd.exe related, it should not be either linux related. In this regard I don't understand how the post title has been renamed : There is no problem with linux (I write it clearly I think), problem is under windows/cmd.exe....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with make.  As you say, it's the operating system which doesn't recognize the difference in case.  If the filesystem doesn't support filenames that differ only in case, then there's nothing a program like make can do about it.

You'll have to name your files differently in more than just case: you'll have to use `.s` and `.sc` or something else, not `.s` and `.S`.

Comment: Great, this is the right direction... and leads to the response. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to MadScientist, solution is indeed using another extension than an upper-case one.
I first tried a random one (.sp) but it was rejected by gcc. In my case, for asm files which require preprocessing, appropriate extension is .sx. Just a light rework of the makefile for those files solved it all !
Thanks again MadScientist.